# Integrating google maps in polymer

Tags: polymer

I am new to polymer js.
I am trying to build an application that integrates google maps.
I had tried using bower dependency by the command **bower install PolymerLabs/google-map --save** and imported the dependency html  in my polymer element and used the custom google-map tag

The end result is a empty page and i didnot get any maps on the html page.
I tried all means but i am unable to get the map.

Can anyone help me cross this hurdle,

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you post some of your code? Have you looked at the [docs](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/google-map) for the `google-map` element? Are you setting a width/height for the `google-map`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<google-map latitude="37.77493" longitude="-122.41942" style="height:600px">
</google-map>
```

In order to work properly, the `<google-map>` tag requires certain attributes like `latitude` and `longitude` coordinates as well as a `style:height`.

Also, more than one `<google-map>` tag on the same page breaks everything and neither map renders properly.

Comment: Feel free to accept any answers that work for you. You can also upvote or provide feedback on the answers too. What works for you, what doesn't etc.